# How can I convert from a Javascript Buffer to a String only containing 0 and 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, fs, huffman-code

So I currently am trying to implement the huffman alg and it works fine for decoding and encoding. However, I store the encoded data as follows.

The result of the encoding function is a list containing many strings made up of 0 and 1 and all are varying length.

If i'd safe them in a normal txt file it would take up more space, if Id store them how they are in a binary file it could be that for example an 'e' which would have the code 101 would be stored in a full 8 bits looking like '00000101' which is wasteful and wont take up less storage then the original txt file. I took all the strings in the list and put them into one string and split it into equal parts of length 8 to store them more effectively.

However if I wanna read the data now, instead of 0 and 1 I get utf-8 chars, even some escape characters.

I'm reading the file with `fs.readFileSync("./encoded.bin", "binary");` but javascript then thinks it's a buffer already and converts it to a string and it gets all weird... Any solutions or ideas to convert it back to 0 and 1?

I also tried to switch the "binary" in `fs.readFileSync("./encoded.bin", "binary");` to a "utf-8" which helped with not crashing my terminal but still is "#��C��Ʃ��Ԧ�y�Kf�g��<�e�t"

To clarify, my goal in the end is to read out the massive string of binary data which would look like this "00011001000101001010" and actually get this into a string...

Comment: can you share any sample .bin file?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `String` of `1`s and `0`s to the numerical representation of a byte using `Number.parseInt(str, 2)` and to convert it back, you can use `nr.toString(2)`.

The entire process will look something like this:

```js
const original = '0000010100000111';
// Split the string in 8 char long substrings
const stringBytes = original.match(/.{8}/g);
// Convert the 8 char long strings to numerical byte representations
const numBytes = stringBytes.map((s) => Number.parseInt(s, 2));
// Convert the numbers to an ArrayBuffer
const buffer = Uint8Array.from(numBytes);
// Write to file


// Read from file and reverse the process
const decoded = [...buffer].map((b) => b.toString(2).padStart(8, '0')).join('');

console.log('original', original, 'decoded', decoded, 'same', original === decoded);
```

Comment: I tried doing the following `[...fs.readFileSync("./encoded.bin", "binary")].map((b) => console.log(b.toString(2)));` which I hope was what you meant but the output is weirdly still the same => "2#ºCÿÙÆ©²Ô¦ÜyÆKfñg<e"
While the .bin file contains following "2#��C��Ʃ��Ԧ�y�Kf�g��<�e�t"

Comment: @RoyalFoxy That won't work, you also have to encode the data the way I've illustrated in my answer. You'll have to do something like `fs.writeSync('./encoded.bin', buffer)` and then `[...fs.readFileSync('./encoded.bin', 'binary')].map((b) => b.toString(2).padStart(8, '0')).join('')` will work as expected.

Comment: I'm already saving it as a buffer... I think
`fs.writeFileSync("encoded.bin", Buffer.from(encode(string, codes).join("").match(/.{1,8}/g), "binary"));`

I also tried to make a test file now that would just safe a few 0 and 1 to a file and would read it out again but node thinks the three dots are an unexpected token
`[...fs.readFileSync("./encoded.bin", "binary")].map((b) => console.log(b.toString(2)));`
  The three dots at the start

Comment: Instead of `[...fs.readFileSync("./encoded.bin", "binary")]` use `Array.from(fs.readFileSync("./encoded.bin", "binary"))`. It is not enough to save the data as binary, it matters how you encode it, if you don't encode it as in my example, this won't work.

Comment: The binary representation of the string `00000101` is different then the binary representation of an 8-bit unsigned integers that has its bits set to `00000101`. In the first case you'll have 8 values, in the second case you'll have just one.

Answer (score 0):

```
var binary = fs.readFileSync("./binary.bin");
binary = [...binary].map((b) => b.toString(2).padStart(8, "0")).join("");
console.log(binary);

//Output will be like 010000111011010
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It could be improved by adding an explanation as to what your code is doing and why.